# in chrome or firefox,why has padding-bottom in this code?

Tags: html, css

i using doctype:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd
```

full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<BODY>
<div style="border:1px solid red;background-color:blue;"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

you can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/766pb/)

in chrome or firefox,why has a padding on bottom?

how to fix it?

(if I remove doctype, or in IE ,it's be okey)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the image to `display: block` [(preview)](http://jsfiddle.net/766pb/9/), and it will no longer generate a line box. (Also, be aware that jsFiddle is annoying for doctype switching since it wraps your HTML.)

Read about the [inline formatting model](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html) and [almost standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: jleedev has the right answer. not deleting this because it is often the answer to this sort of issue

Different browsers have different "default" styles for elements. One popular technique is to use a "[CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/)" stylesheet, that sets everything to neutral values for you, so that you can get consistent results across browsers.

Comment: That has no effect in this case. CSS 2.1 recommends that image should have display:inline by default anyway — note that the reset stylesheet is more concerned with fonts, colors, margins and padding, and does not change any display property.

Comment: @jleedev: you are totally right. I didn't take the time to really look at what he was talking about, usually random margins and padding on different browsers mean the user agent stylesheets are different. voting you up